# How to change numpy's intc value from 32 to 64 bit

Tags: python, numpy, 32bit-64bit, sparse-matrix, type-conversion

I'm facing a problem with numpy's intc datatype. I'm running a Linux 64 bit on my machine. I need to instantiate a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix with indexes beyond the 32 bit limit. For instance:

I have instantiated a csr matrix like that:

```
matrix=csr_matrix((2, 4132009369),dtype=int8)
```

This gaves me no problem. Then, somewhere in the code I do, let's say:

```
matrix[0, 2401803431]=1
```

And I got `ValueError: column index values must be >= 0`. I debug the code and I discovered that somewhere in the scipy's implementation of csr_matrix the column value is converted to a numpy's intc datatype.
To ensure it is an intc problem I checked with the following code:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> info=np.iinfo(np.intc)
>>> info.max
2147483647
```

that value is 2^31-1.
So, do you have any suggestion if there's a way to go from 32 bit intc to a 64 bit intc? In this page http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html it says that

```
intc    Identical to C int (normally int32 or int64)
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 2):

I solved by upgrading scipy library to the latest version (previously I had 1.3, now 1.4)

Comment: I think you mean you upgraded from 0.13 to 0.14.